# How to get pathInfo with SecurityWrapperRequest?

Tags: java, esapi

i am applying esapi security filter to my application, am enabling/disabling this security filter using a property from conf.properties file.
It is working fine when it is disabled but i am not able to access my application when it is enabled
Here is my piece of code:

```
    if(this.owaspSecurityEnabled) 
    {

                // this is necessary on every call
                ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(servletRequest, servletResponse);

                // doFilter by wrapping the request and the response to the 
                // ESAPI safe HttpServletRequest and  HttpServletResponse  
                request = new SecurityWrapperRequest(servletRequest);
                response = new SecurityWrapperResponse(servletResponse);
    }
```

and i have debugged the issue but could not solve it.
am getting request.getPathInfo() as "" when it is enabled and returning path when it is disabled.

How to solve this issue, Please help me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution to my problem, It is with the regrular expresion in espai.properties file

```
"Validator.HTTPPath=^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]*$" changed to "Validator.HTTPPath=^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_\/]*$"
```

Thanks..